# Not getting date format using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all dates in between 2 dates. So here I have mentioned statdate is date and end date is weekdate. In between 2 dates I  want all dates.

Actully I am getting all dates But Not proper Format ,what i want in this format `DD/MM/YY`.

Now I am Getting in default Format (Sat Jun 09 2007 17:46:21)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#day").click(function () {
        startJsonSession();
        return false;
    });
    function startJsonSession() {
        var inputdate = $('#inputdate').val();
        //alert("Input Date!!!" + inputdate );
        var d = new Date(inputdate);
        var nowMS = d.getTime(); // get # milliseconds for today
        //alert(nowMS);
        var week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // milliseconds in one week
        //alert(week);
        var oneWeekFromNow = new Date(nowMS + week);
        //alert("oneWeekFromNow!!!" + oneWeekFromNow);
        var fromdate = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (fromdate < 10) {
            fromdate = "0" + fromdate;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        //var date = fromdate + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        var date = year + "/" + month + "/" + fromdate;
        alert("InputDate!!!!" + date);

        //var weekdate=oneWeekFromNow.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        var weekdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + oneWeekFromNow.getDate();
        alert("weekdate!!!" + weekdate);
        var tomorrow = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var tomorrowdate = tomorrow.getDate();
        var month1 = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
        var year1 = tomorrow.getFullYear();
        if (tomorrowdate < 10) {
            tomorrowdate = "0" + tomorrowdate;
        }
        if (month1 < 10) {
            month1 = "0" + month1;
        }
        //var nextday = tomorrowdate + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1;
        var nextday = year1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + tomorrowdate;
        alert("tomorrow!!!!" + nextday);
        var d1 = new Date(date);
        alert("D1!!!!!" + d1.);
        var d2 = new Date(weekdate);
        var aDates = [];
        do {
            aDates.push(d1.toString());
            d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1);
        }
        while (d1 <= d2);
        alert("Dates!!!" + aDates);
        //alert(aDates.join("\n")); 
    }
});
```

Comment: `new Date(inputdate)` is reliant on *Date.parse*, which is implementation dependent, even for the format specified in ES5. Adding one week is a simple as `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7)`, similar for adding one day to get *tomorrow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
$("#getDate").click(function () {
    var start = $("#startdate").datepicker("getDate"),
        end = $("#enddate").datepicker("getDate");

    currentDate = new Date(start),
    between = [];
    while (currentDate < end) {
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
        var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(between[i]));
        between[i] = date;
    }
    console.log(between)
})
```

Here **'between'** is the array which contains all your required Date
[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/odrqy0dx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  alert("Dates!!!" + aDates.getDate()+"/"+ (aDates.getMonth()+1)+"/"+ aDates.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Code–only answers are not liked. Explain why the OP's code doesn't work and why yours does.

Comment: Because you call simple alert Date() to string it will return default format

Comment: if wrote like this what u Mention ,,Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'getDate' is showing....@tuan hunyh

Comment: I didn't get u....@ RobG,if i did like this only date will show not month and year.

Comment: Thanks Roshan..Itz Working For Me..:)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to get a array of date strings in d/m/y format given an input string in the same format. The following functions will do that.

```
// Parse a string in dmy format
// return a date object, NaN or undefined
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\d+/g);
  if (b) {
    return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  }
}

// Given a date object, return a string in dd/mm/yyyy format
function formatDMY(date) {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
  return z(date.getDate()) + '/' + z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}

function getWeekDates(s) {
  var d = parseDMY(s);
  var dates = [];
  if (d) {
    for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
      dates.push(formatDMY(d));
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return dates;
  }
}

console.log(getWeekDates('7/7/2014').join());
// 07/07/2014,08/07/2014,09/07/2014,10/07/2014,11/07/2014,12/07/2014,13/07/2014
```

Note that adding 1 day to a date is preferred over adding milliseconds as it allows the Date object to take account of daylight saving changes that might be involved.